# MVC & Jquery validation: Disabled Dropdownlists gets validate, how can make it not happen

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using MVC3, EF Model first.

I have a form with two DropDownList that gets disabled depending on what value the user choose on another dropdownlist, i've used Jquery for this here is the code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#SubjectTypeName').change(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if (value == '2') {
            $('#TeamName, #ConsultantName').removeAttr('disabled');
        } else if (value == '3') {
            $('#TeamName').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $('#ConsultantName').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else if (value == '4') {
            $('#TeamName').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $('#ConsultantName').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }

        $(".questionsForSubjectType").hide();
        $("#questionsForSubjectType_" + value).show();
    });

})
```

But when the DropDownList is disabled and I click on next page, the disabled DropDownLists gets validated by MVC standard Jquery validation that I have. I've done the validation by declaring [Required] on my properties in my ViewModel for this validation. How can I prevent the validation on my disabled DropDownlists but still make sure the DropDownLists gets validated if they are enabled

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: An inelegant solution: when you disable the DDL, set it's property to 'disabled for validation' or 'used only for validation hack'. Your server side logic should know not to use it. Can you modify my sample http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/01/09/cascasding-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx to reproduce the problem? Then post the simple project and ask for a more elegant soln.

Comment: Hi Rick, I found a solution that works, I will post it when i'm back home. I just simply made a Jquery function that validates my form and if statement that says do not validate "Disabled". Do you see this incorrect way of solving it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the `[Required]` attribute on the field the dropdown is for set? Perhaps removing this could help if that is the case.

You could also consider populating partial views based on user input.

Comment: Thank you I used [RequiredIf] instead and now it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

does the MVC validation occur at client side or server side? 
At server side you could check if dropdown_A was used, `ModelState.Remove("dropdown_B");` then your `ModelState.IsValid` will be true.

Comment: Server side, But we want to do this remove only when the dropdownlist is disabled. n